# Disk based indexing for multi dimensional data

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, indexing, r-tree

I want to use some kinda disk based indexing for multi dimensional data. I want to be able

1. to perform range searches - (10 - 20% of application usage)
2. faster retrieval - (80%)

data size ( in order of GBs) and record count in order of billions

To be more specific, I want to implement something like R-Tree, or X-Tree. But I thought it is a good idea to get started with B-Trees. Although all the databases offer very efficient
implementations of B-Tree, i want to be able to tune the design, add possible
application based heuristics to the design so I would prefer to implement something
of my own or to use some library as a starting point.

Any pointers to libraries, or suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: See Hanan Samet: Foundations of Multidimesnional and Metric Data Structures

Comment: Is it 2D or could it be higher dimensions? Try searching the web for orthogonal range search, it might be helpful here.

Comment: Were I you, I would use a database for this, initially.  The reason for this is that 1) you may find that using a RDBMS may do what you need and 2) it will give you a baseline for what your implementation need to do.

Comment: mysql and postgresql both implement a form of rtree indexing for geographic data. Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible to go above 2D (cartographic coordinates), afair.

Comment: @Davidann Yes I will base line it against existing database based implementation. If I have 10 columns in a table, I have where clauses on 9 columns in the same table. Which is what making me rethink about implementing something on my own.

Comment: @Knoothe literally it could be ten to hundred of dimensions..

Comment: @AlexWien Thanks a lot. Will definitely take a look and see if it helps.

Comment: @Venki: You are probably going to be disappointed. High dimensional range queries can be tricky and efficient implementations might be hard to find. Good luck, I do hope you find something though.

Comment: @venki: have you thought about using a graph database for this?  E.g. neo4J or something like it?

Answer (score 0):

"Retrieval" - by what? Window queries? Radius queries? Nearest neighbor queries?

How many dimensions - if it's just 2D, even simple grid approaches may work very well.

Note that most quality SQL systems (pretty much everything except MySQL actually) have support for R-trees to some extend.

Comment: by retrieval I mean point queries. I do not need Radius or Knn. No of dimensions may be between 10-40

Comment: That is exact match? Use a hash table for that, it's O(1), not O(log n).

Comment: The data is huge. It does not fit in to memory. Also please note that Hash table is not one stop magic solution. As the number of items increases in your hash table, how your hash table is implemented matters. If the hashtable is implemented through chained lists and you have too many elements in your list. its no more o(1)

Comment: Well, if you know your data will be huge, you should of course use a huge on-disk hashtable, and not your average in-memory linked-list implementation... But of course, if you retrieve by key only, B+-Trees are another choice.